# Animation tool for basic demonstration

Tags: animation

I want to create a demonstrative animation for a video, I am wondering that which tool will be good for that. I know that animation is labour intensive but it will be a waste of time and skill if I learn an animation centric tool and only use it for basic demonstration.......so which animation tool will be suitable or should I even opt for an animation centric tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend Adobe After Effects. It sure is not cheap, but its easy to learn and you can achieve anything in it. Also there are tons of tutorials and templates which you can use to make a nice looking animation. No other software offers that.

Comment: Anything for Linux?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145/is-there-an-alternative-to-adobe-aftereffects

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AnimationMaker. 
It's very easy to use and you can create movies like mp4, avi and also animated gifs are supported.

https://artanidos.github.io/AnimationMaker/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft PowerPoint's animation features are quite powerful. And simple to use as well. The slides can be exported to a video format.